# How can I produce a backslash on a Lenovo X260 keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, lenovo, keyboard-layout, input-devices

I have started running Ubuntu 23.04 on a Lenovo Thinkpad X260 in the UK.

Its keyboard has hash, tilde and backslash on the same key.

Using Right Alt and this key presents the ` grave accent input placeholder.

I have tried combinations of left and right alts and changed the *Settings> Keyboard> Special Character Entry >Alternative Character Key*, but this only sets the grave placeholder again.

I've looked at the *Settings> Keyboard> Input Sources>* Keyboard (UK) and testing the layout, there is no key or key combination to activate the pipe and backslash key.

How can I force Right Alt to, or otherwise, produce a backslash with this keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [an answer from superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/701797/how-can-i-type-a-backslash-with-no-backslash-key), it is possible:

> <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> gives `\`.